# How disable last <td> from clicking?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to disable last  from clicking because that column contains the delete action button.

I do not want to use JS or JQuery, I was wondering if it is posible to disable it inside HTML tag code.

This is not a duplicated question because most similar questions include the use of JS or Jquery which I don't want to use.

```
<tr onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("DetallePedido", "Pedidos", new { id = pedido.Id })'" class="bg-warning">
            <td>@pedido.Id</td>
            <td>@pedido.FechaPedido</td>
            <td>@pedido.Cliente.Nombres</td>
            <td>@pedido.Region</td>
            <td>@pedido.ContactoPrincipal</td>
            <td>@pedido.Telefonoc</td>
            <td>@pedido.SubTotal</td>
            <td>@pedido.Total</td>
            <td>@pedido.FechaEntrega</td>
            <td>@pedido.Direccion</td>
            <td>
                @if (pedido.User != null)
                {
                    @pedido.User.Name
                } else
                {
                    @pedido.Vendedor
                }

            </td>
            <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs text-white" onclick="cancelarPedido(@pedido.Id)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set CSS `style="pointer-events: none;"` to the delete link. See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

It's not very nice solution though, you'd better just change the onclick attribute to `return: false;`.